# Why is this method returning an ArrayList with all the same objects? JAVA

Tags: java, file, csv, arraylist, bufferedreader

I have a class called `User` and a file called `Users.csv`, like below:

**User class:**

```
public class User
{
private String name;
private String rg;
private String type;

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getRg()
{
    return rg;
}

public String getType()
{
    return type;
}

public void setName(String n)
{
    name = n;
}

public void setRg(String r)
{
    rg = r;
}

public void setType(String t)
{
    type = t;
}
}
```

**Users.csv:**

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
as,d,cf
```

Also, I have a class called `test`, which implements a single method:

**test class:**

```
public class test
{
public ArrayList<User> readUsers(String path) throws IOException //read all users from file and returns an ArrayList
{       
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    String[] str;
    User u = new User();
    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String line = buffRead.readLine(); 
    while(line != null)
    {
            str = line.split(",");
            u.setName(str[0]); //sets each field read to "u"
            u.setRg(str[1]);
            u.setType(str[2]);
            list.add(u); //adding user to the list to be returned
            line = buffRead.readLine(); //reading next register
    }
buffRead.close();
return list;
}
}
```

The problem is in the method `readUsers()`. It is returning me an ArrayList where every element is the same, and they are the one at the last line of `Users.csv`.
Any tip why it is happening? I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How many times do you call `new User()`? That's how many User objects you've created: exactly **one**, and you do this once **before** the loop.

Solution, call this **inside** of the loop -- this way you create a new User for each item that you add to the list.

Comment: But why isn't it okay to, for each loop, set User's Name, Rg and type, then add him t the list? Each time the values change, I add the user to the list

Comment: This is the answer right there that I was just about to give. Please make sure you mark  this one as correct.

Comment: @Quik19: There are two main causes of the symptoms that you've described -- re-filling the same object over-and-over (what you're doing) or over-use of static variables (a mistake that you're not making).

Answer (score 4):

You've only created a single instance of `User` and are simply changing it's properties.  You will need to create a new instance of `User` for each entry in the CSV file

```
//User u = new User();
//...
while(line != null)
{
        str = line.split(",");
        User u = new User();
        u.setName(str[0]); //sets each field read to "u"
        u.setRg(str[1]);
        u.setType(str[2]);
        list.add(u); //adding user to the list to be returned
        line = buffRead.readLine(); //reading next register
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The answer was simple but it was killing me! I'm so dumb haha!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to my world ;)

Answer (score 2):

Java collections store references. Thus, in your code, there is a single User object, and the reference to it is being added to the ArrayList on each iteration (different than what happens in C++, where the vector does a copy). You need something like:

```
while(line != null)
{
   str = line.split(",");
   User u = new User();
   u.setName(str[0]); //sets each field read to "u"
   u.setRg(str[1]);
   u.setType(str[2]);
   list.add(u); //adding user to the list to be returned
   line = buffRead.readLine(); //reading next register
}
```